# Outer dimension for outputs must be unknown

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

When i tried to deploy MASKRCNN model https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN to google ai platform, I get this error:

```
WARNING: Using endpoint [https://ml.googleapis.com/]
Creating version (this might take a few minutes)......failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Model validation failed: Outer dimension for outputs must be unknown, outer dimension of 'mrcnn_detection/Reshape_1:0' is 1
```

Any Idea how to solve it, here's the signature def of my model:

```
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['input_anchors'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, -1, 4)
        name: input_anchors:0
    inputs['input_image'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, -1, -1, 3)
        name: input_image:0
    inputs['input_image_meta'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 14)
        name: input_image_meta:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['mrcnn_detection/Reshape_1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 100, 6)
        name: mrcnn_detection/Reshape_1:0
    outputs['mrcnn_mask/Reshape_1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (1, 100, 28, 28, 2)
        name: mrcnn_mask/Reshape_1:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Heres the script that I use to generate tf-serving model: https://github.com/moganesyan/tensorflow_model_deployment/blob/master/tf_serving/make_tf_serving.py

How can this error be fixed ?

I have referenced [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557979/google-cloud-ml-outer-dimension-for-outputs-must-be-unknown) but couldn't find a solid solution.

Comment: I see what is the cause of the error from the model signature. The inputs to the model are defined as unknown batch size (-1). So the same needs to be true for the outputs. Example: mrcnn_detection:/Reshape_1 should be (-1, 100, 6)

Comment: @Andrew-OpenGeoCode here's the code which generates the output: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/3deaec5d902d16e1daf56b62d5971d428dc920bc/mrcnn/model.py#L820.  If I do [-1, self.config.DETECTION_MAX_INSTANCES, 6] will that do the trick ?