# What does it mean for a tensor to have shape [None, x] in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I define a tf placeholder as:

```
tf.placeholder("float", [None, 10])
```

what does the `None` do? What is the linear algebra interpretation of this? A horizontal vector?

Comment: May be answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41784379/5916727 may be helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `None` value in the shape of a tensor means that the tensor can be of any size (large than or equal to 1) in that dimension. E.g., for the `tf.placeholder` you defined in your question, you could pass a arrays with shapes like

```
[1234, 10]
[10, 10]
[1, 10]
```

but not an array of shape `[10,]` (i.e. a vector).