# Numpy array loses a dimension converting to tf dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to convert numpy arrays into a `tf.data.Dataset` by using the following code:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((traininput, train[:, :, :, 1:4]))
```

However my dataset is now missing its first dimension. The numpy arrays both have the shape 1000, 128, 128, 3 and the dataset is reduced to the shape 128, 128, 3. This then leads to an error when trying to train my model:
Error when checking input: `expected input_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (128, 128, 3)`
I have tried to work according to the [tensorflow tutorial on loading numpy data](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy).
Why is that happening and how may I fix it?

As suggested I am providing a mcve below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
inp = np.random.rand(100, 128, 128, 3)
out = np.random.rand(100, 126, 126, 3)
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(128, 128, 3)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
              filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
                      filters=3,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      strides=(2, 2),
                      padding="SAME",
                      activation='relu'),
    ]
)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inp, out))
model_history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10)
```

It terminates with: `Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (128, 128, 3)`

Comment: Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Isn't this expected? See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices Specifically: *This operation preserves the structure of the input tensors, removing the first dimension of each tensor and using it as the dataset dimension* It's hard to help any more without a [mcve] to see exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `batch` size on the dataset so that it returns multiple examples instead of just one. This will also change the number of dimensions to be 4.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
inp = np.random.rand(100, 128, 128, 3)
# *** Had to set the last dim below to 1 to avoid another error with the accuracy
out = np.random.rand(100, 126, 126, 1)
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(128, 128, 3)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
              filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
                      filters=3,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      strides=(2, 2),
                      padding="SAME",
                      activation='relu'),
    ]
)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inp, out))
# *** Setting batch size of 10 below
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(10)
model_history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10)
```

Note: I had to change the last dimension of the `out` tensor to avoid a different error:

```
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[3], expected a dimension of 1, got 3 for 'metrics/accuracy/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,126,126,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you have 100 images of size 128x128, which are 3-channel(RGB). And you network cannot get all of you images at once. It should get one image at one step. So you have 2 options:

1. use for loop to iterate over you dataset, get one image input and one output image from dataset
2. use batch. Tell you network that you will be using batches: `tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(None, 128, 128, 3))` - [Tensorflow batch size in input placholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783136/tensorflow-batch-size-in-input-placholder)